# beautifulsoup 4 multiple class values regex

Tags: python, regex, class, beautifulsoup

I got the following tags:

```
<span class="one two-l three-project">not interested in</span>
<span class="one two-xl">interesting 1</span>
<span class="one two-l">interesting 2</span>
```

How do I select the 2 lower spans w/o selecting the first one?

I tried:

```
html.find_all('span', attrs={'class' : re.compile(r'(one two-)'}) // doesn't select anything

html.find_all('span', attrs={'class' : re.compile(r'(?!three-project)')}) // does select all

html.find_all('span', attrs={'class' : 'one two-xl')}) // doesn't select the 3rd one

html.select('span.one.two-xl') // doesn't select the 3rd one
```

Any ideas are really appreciated :-)

Comment: unfortunately bs4 interprets "one two-l three-project" not as a whole large string, but 3 strings (one, two-l and three-project). therefore "one two-x?l(?! three-project)" won't match at all.

Comment: Beautifulsoup is not very good at things like this, what you want it  http://lxml.de/, is there anything unique in the text you could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limitations in `BeautifulSoup` functionality mean it is tricky to select tags *with* some classes, but *without* other classes. Instead of using regex, I would use a list comprehension to iterate over all of the spans and select the relevant ones with an `if` statement.

You could do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''
<span class="one two-l three-project">not interested in</span>
<span class="one two-xl">interesting 1</span>
<span class="one two-l">interesting 2</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
desired_tags = [tag for tag in soup.find_all('span') if 'three-project' not in tag.attrs['class']]
print(desired_tags)
```

**Output**

```
[<span class="one two-xl">interesting 1</span>,
 <span class="one two-l">interesting 2</span>]
```